# How to compare the performance of two spark streaming jobs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-kafka

My spark job is consuming data from a kafka topic and performing some operations. The difference comes in the serialization, one is using java serialization and the other is using kryo serialization. How to compare these two streaming jobs as they have a different number of inputs per second and different input batch size in the same time interval?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to calculate time required to process single input.

Say you get batch with 1000 records. Measure whole process time and divide by 1000. You got processing time of single record.
Collect that info for multiple batches and then compare results.

Comment: In one batch there are say 1000 records, and it took 20s for one job and 21s for another job,now there are incoming next batches with say 900records or 999 records and so on, now the processing time at one time it is lower for one anf a little higher then the other and vice versa at random time intervals. Should i need to calculate manually, is there another way @Vladislav Varslavans

Comment: Why manually? you could write a code to do it for you. And then print result to logs. Also you might be interested in stateful transformations - https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/spark-streaming-stateful-transformations/